# Why does printing an object fail with a "no match for 'operator<<'" error?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have created a dynamic memory as `s_points`, which has the type `PointList`. `PointList` is vector of integer values. I have appended to `s_points` by getting some values from another list of data. Now I want to visualise my `s_points` to check whether it is updated or not, but I have an error:

```
no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << (&z)->__gnu_cxx::
__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*
[with _Iterator = Number*, _Container = std::vector<Number,
std::allocator<Number> >]()'
```

Here is my code:

```
MyPoints::iterator point;
PointList *s_points = new PointList;
for (point=my_points.begin();point!=my_points.end();point++){
     s_points->push_back(point->Attribute(NumberTag));
}
PointList::iterator z;
for(z=s_points->begin();z!=s_points->end();z++){cout<<*z<<" ";}
```

Please help me understand this error.

Comment: Plz rectify this question, first. What exactly are you asking here? What is it you want to do?

Comment: You need to tell us more about `PointList`. Is it a `typedef` to `vector<int>`? I think not. Maybe a `vector<Number>` ? If so, you need to tell us more about `Number`. Give us all more code, especially for all types you've defined yourself.

Comment: @ Aaron, yes you are write. it was vector<Number>. i use z->Number(), then i got the value. thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error speaks for itself. You don't have `operator<<()` defined for `Number`.